# qt "wildcard" in connect signals

Tags: qt, signals-slots

In Qt, one can connect a signal to a slot using:

```
connect(x, SIGNAL(S()), y, SLOT(func()));
```

Where x and y are pointers to instances of a class that inherits from QObject.

I am looking for something like:

```
connect(*, SIGNAL(S()), y, SLOT(func()));
```

Which would connect anyone sending the signal S to slot func() of y.
Or:

```
connect(C, SIGNAL(S()), y, SLOT(func()));
```

where C would design a class (not only an instance), so that all signals S emitted by any instance of C would get connected.

I assume it should be possible to use these "wildcards" instead of 'y' as well:

```
connect (x, SIGNAL(S()), C, SLOT(func()));
```

would connect signal S of instance x to any instance of class C

How does one do that in Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends very much on whether the class in question is under your control or not.  There is no way to do a wild card connect exactly as you describe, but you can get the same effect by using event filters (for a class not your own) or by changing the class to emit a specific signal each time any signal is received (if it is your own).  If neither of those work then wrapping an existing class could allow you to add the required feature.

In short, there is no general solution, so let us know more specific details about the specific situation.

Comment: OK. I already have a work-around using instance to instance connection. I just though I was missing something more generic...

Answer (score 1):

My guess as to why there is no magic wildcard approach to connecting all signals from instances of a class to a slot, is because the class would have to track all of its instances to iterate over them and make the connection. And doing a connection after that call was made would require the class installing something onto the end of its constructor so that future instances will also get the connection made. 
All in all, It would be a matter of you subclassing the class and adding this into the constructor. If you wont know the slot at the time of construction, you would need to have the class track the instances so that you could later call your own wildcard signal slot connection method.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you aren't doing this in the constructor of the relevant classes? Any time you are wanting to do something to all instances of a class, that is a good place to start. Have the constructor take a pointer to the object with the signal (or slot), and make the connection the normal way - with the `this` pointer in place of `x` or `y`.

Comment: The order in which things are constructed is random, so it makes things a bit complicated. I can build some logic around this, but something more generic would be nice... if it exists...